# How to Use Eclipse to Debug JNI code (Java & C/C++)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface, android-ndk

While I can debug my application with the Eclipse JDT debugger for Java code and GDB for C code, I would prefer to use a single tool for all my debugging.  I found several projects that enable "mixed-mode" debugging in Eclipse and include support for single stepping between Java and native code.

- [Intel's Integrated Debugger for Java/JNI Environments](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/integrated-debugger-for-javajni-environments/)
- [Mariot Chauvin's Summer of Code Project: Support Seamless Debugging between JDT & CDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Support_seamless_debugging_between_JDT_and_CDT)

Unfortunately, one claims to be pre-release quality and the other is currently unmaintained.
**Are there any plug-ins that bring mixed mode debugging functionality to Eclipse in a reliable way or should I continue to use two separate debuggers?**

Comment: Till you have some support available, you can build out a linux executable and test it on linux PC using GDB. Not a great idea, but it can solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything available today which will fix it, but I know that Doug Schaefer has this pretty high on his list of things he wants to get done. Keep an eye on [his blog](http://cdtdoug.blogspot.com/) for updates on that.

Answer (score 5):

For those looking to debug NDK/JNI code in the Eclipse Juno release, it is essentially built into the software after installing the Android plugins and CDT plugins.  You may have issues though since there is a problem that was introduced with the C/C++ Development tools (CDT 8.1) that as of 7/24/12 has not been fixed.  For details on the issue see the following link.  If you just want to debug, keep reading.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

If it is working correctly, you simply set your breakpoints in the C and **Debug As -> Android Native Application**.  Unfortunately, you can not debug the java and C at the same time.  If the problem is in the Java and you want to debug you do so by clicking **Debug As -> Android Application**.

If it is not working correctly, and you want to figure out how to get it correctly, the following packages worked for me.

```
  Android DDMS  20.0.1.v201207132230-403220
  Android Development Tools 20.0.1.v201207132230-403220 
  Android Hierarchy Viewer  20.0.1.v201207132230-403220 
  Android Native Development Tools  20.0.1.v201207132230-403220 
  Android Traceview 20.0.1.v201207132230-403220 
  Autotools support for CDT (Incubation)    3.0.1.201202152032  
  C/C++ Development Tools   8.0.2.201202111925  
  C/C++ Development Tools SDK   8.0.2.201202111925
  C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help (Incubation)   
  Eclipse SDK   4.2.0.I20120608-1400    
  Tracer for OpenGL ES  20.0.1.v201207132230-403220
```

The android packages came from setting *Work With:* option on the Eclipse **Help->Install New Software...** dialog to

```
dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

The older 8.02... CDT packages came from setting the *Work With:* option to the Indigo release packages.

```
download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
```

If installed, you will need to remove the Android tools, and the new version of the CDT prior to installing the old version of the CDT.  Once the 8.02... version of CDT is installed, you can install the Android tools and commence debugging.

Ensure you use the Build command "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1"

Autotools may not be required but since it is installed I have it listed.

Note that stepping through the code can be quirky sometimes.

Comment: I'm resurrecting this comment to note that Java code *can* be debugged at the same time as Native JNI code.  To do so, start by Debugging as an Android Native Application. Next attach to the Android process in the ADT Devices tab (select process, and click the green bug icon).  Breakpoints in both Java and C++ code will now be hit.  Not quite seamless, but close enough.

Answer (score 2):

ARM itself seems to have a toolkit: http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/

Requires Eclipse 4.4 ("Luna").

Comment: Would be possible to use it to debug Java regular apps using JNI?

Answer (score 1):

With the new Android ADT bundle (as of 05/12/2013), there is no longer a need for the older 8.02 software package.  If you find yourself editing text files to get the debugging working, you are following old directions that no longer apply.  Use the android ADT and Debug As-> Android Native Application.  You may still need to set NDK_DEBUG=1 if its not already done in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Sequoyah 1.0 has android ndk features..Eclipse 3.6 release train and 3.5 release early June.