# How to debug native side of Android stack?

Tags: android, native

Below given is the logcat of the signal11 obtained from our stack:

```
__ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
Cpu0[.tel.tv.watchtv:1644:0x7ef12814:0xdeadbaad] no fix-ups.
I/ActivityManager( 1422): Process com.tel.tv.watchtv (pid 1600) has died.
I/WindowManager( 1422): WIN DEATH: Window{34ad9f10 com.tel.tv.watchtv/com.tel.tv.watcem8xxx0 [/relea
se/android_mrua_dcchd_SMP8644_3_8_2/mrua/MRUA_src/rua/emhwlib_kernel/kernel_src/krua.c:865] em8xxx_r
elease: unclean exit (37 entries)
htv.WatchTv paused=false}
I/WindowManager( 1422): WIN DEATH: Window{34adba60 SurfaceView paused=false}
I/UsageStats( 1422): Unexpected resume of com.tel.application.home while already resumed in com.tel.
tv.watchtv
D/Zygote  ( 1325): Process 1600 terminated by signal (10)
W/InputManagerService( 1422): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1600
uid 10009
D/UInput  ( 1337): DVD remote: 0xea15e608, key: 0x0000001c, desc: ENTER
I/System.out( 1509): HomeScreen.onKey()2131034114
I/ActivityManager( 1422): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.tel.tv.
watchtv/.WatchTv }
W/Process ( 1422): Unable to open /proc/1600/status
I/ActivityManager( 1422): Start proc com.tel.tv.watchtv for activity com.tel.tv.watchtv/.WatchTv: pi
d=1645 uid=10009 gids={}
D/WatchTv ( 1645): Watch TV
D/dalvikvm( 1645): GC freed 582 objects / 50376 bytes in 95ms
D/dalvikvm( 1645): GC freed 159 objects / 7064 bytes in 54ms
D/dalvikvm( 1645): Trying to load lib /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so 0x34c0bf88
V/DCCHD   ( 1645): [src/CMediaAccess.cpp:375] [Global]MediaAccess object created
D/dalvikvm( 1645): Added shared lib /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so 0x34c0bf88
W/dalvikvm( 1645): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/canon/eejni/common/nativeclasses/IfIni
t;.siEventRecv ()com/canon/eejni/common/events/SIEvent
W/dalvikvm( 1645): ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/canon/eejni/common/nativeclasses/Tuner
;.enumerateTuner ()[I}
D/dalvikvm( 1645): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'siEventRecv' (wrong CL)
D/dalvikvm( 1645): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so' for 'siEventRecv' (wrong CL)
D/dalvikvm( 1645): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libexif.so' for 'siEventRecv' (wrong CL)
D/dalvikvm( 1645): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libsrec_jni.so' for 'siEventRecv' (wrong CL)
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): Build fingerprint: 'SigmaDesigns/smp86xx/smp86xx/:2.1/ERD79/eng.arjuntj.20360306.
155623:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): pid: 1645, tid: 1654  >>> com.tel.tv.watchtv <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00688b98
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  zr 00000000  at 00000001  v0 00000001  v1 30257d1c
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  a0 0000000c  a1 30257d34  a2 00688b98  a3 30257d40
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  t0 00688cd8  t1 30257d40  t2 00000000  t3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  t4 30257c90  t5 00000000  t6 00000000  t7 0000001c
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  s0 30257d34  s1 50452ca8  s2 00000001  s3 50452cac
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  s4 00199cf8  s5 00000000  s6 00000002  s7 50452cbc
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  t8 00000000  t9 7ef11a60  k0 00000000  k1 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  gp 5045a570  sp 30257ce8  s8 30257d40  ra 50408c24
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):  hi 003d08db  lo 7ae46b00 bva 00688b98 epc 50408c6c
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):          #00  pc 50408c6c  /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):          #01  ra 50408c24  /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c5c 1000ffeb 8fbc0020 03c03821 24c80140
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c6c 8ccd0000 8ccc0004 8ccb0008 8cca000c
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c7c 24c60010 aced0000 acec0004 aceb0008
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c14 02002821 2406000c 0320f809 2407ffff
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c24 1440fff9 8fbc0020 8fa2004c 1052000c
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): 50408c34 8fa60054 10560049 00000000 8e640000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):
I/DEBUG   ( 1324): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ca8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cac  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cb0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cb4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cb8  00009004
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cbc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cc0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cc4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cc8  30257d34
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ccc  50452ca8  /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cd0  00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cd4  50452cac  /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cd8  00199cf8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cdc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ce0  00000002
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ce4  50408c24  /system/lib/libandroid_JNI.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ce8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cec  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cf0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cf4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cf8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257cfc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d00  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d04  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d08  5045a570
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d0c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d10  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d14  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d18  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d1c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d20  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d24  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d28  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d2c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d30  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d34  00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d38  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d3c  00688b98
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d40  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d44  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d48  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d4c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d50  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d54  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d58  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d5c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d60  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d64  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d68  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d6c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d70  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d74  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d78  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d7c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d80  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d84  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d88  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d8c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d90  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d94  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d98  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257d9c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257da0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257da4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257da8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dac  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257db0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257db4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257db8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dbc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dc0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dc4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dc8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dcc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dd0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dd4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dd8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257ddc  00000000
D/dalvikvm( 1645): GC freed 251 objects / 15528 bytes in 68ms
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257de0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257de4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257de8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dec  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257df0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257df4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257df8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257dfc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e00  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e04  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e08  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e0c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e10  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e14  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e18  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e1c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e20  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e24  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e28  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e2c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e30  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e34  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e38  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e3c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1324):     30257e40  00000000
```

How to get the file and the line where crash is happening ?
Please help !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c). Good luck finding debug symbols for the system libraries, though...