# how to debug native code in android on windows platform

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, native

I have worked with visual studio in c++ now i have write code in c++ and attach it as a lib in android project i have to work on windows platform.
I wrote the c++ code and made the jar file of it and attached the jar file in my android application,i am a beginner to work on native code.now i want to debug the native code(jar file),i searched the net to find the tutorials that how to debug native code in eclipse on android but all the links tell it on linux platform i have to do it on windows can anyone give me a link how to debug native code in android on windows platform,i am new to all this so please give me a beginner link or tell it precisely.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow:) You have 13 other questions unanswered. It might help you to get more responses if you accept the answers that work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Eclipse to Debug JNI code (Java & C/C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging in eclipse is pretty similar to Visual Studio in the sense that you can set break point in the code. You can do this by firstly, adding an Android simulator to your Eclipse softare found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Next you will need to setup the simulator and download the relevent firmware, you can get the SDK required [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Finally, when you run the simulator having put your break points into your code, make sure you run it in debug mode and then you can load up your debugging page by following - Windows - Open Perspective - Debug

Hope this helps,
L&L Partners

Comment: yes this is true for debugging normal java programs.But not for debugging native code.

Comment: it works for C++ too, just compile your programs with a /g directive so gdb can get at the symbols.