# how to debug jvm.dll or java process in gdb , like we debug any other executable?

Tags: java

how to debug jvm.dll or java process  in gdb , like we debug any other executable?
 Normally when we want to create Executable with debug symbols, We use `gcc -g exmaple.c -o exmaple`, So is there any JVM is avialable, So we can debug JVM at runtime?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (that is, unless you're writing your own JVM) You will not debug any java code this way, only the native instructions executed by the JVM binary.

Comment: Do you want to debug the JVM or do you want to debug *your* Java program?

Comment: maybe he/she wants to debug his JNI code? Also if it's just your java code you want to debug, use a java debugger (integrated in eclipse and netbeans)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c)

Comment: No i want to debug JVM not any JNI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to debug the JVM executable, I suggest starting with [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/).

Get the source code, build it from scratch (adding any debug flags you want), and then debug.