# eclipse - debugging Java and C++ code seamlessly

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface

I have a project that is written both in Java and C++ communicating through JNI.
So far I have been working with IntelliJ Idea for debugging the Java code, and Linux native debugger for the C++ code.

As I was looking for alternatives, I thought using Eclipse for debugging would be the best idea for both java and c++. What are the steps for achieving this? (Obviously I want to import my current project).

I'm a Linux 64 bit user, using eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 6):

[Debugging JNI C and Java code in Eclipse](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DebuggingJNICAndJavaCodeInEclipse?_sscc=t) can help you. Otherwise, [How to Use Eclipse to Debug JNI code (Java & C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c) might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is the only existing mature "single GUI" solution AFAIK. My usage practice as answer to similar question:

[JAVA JNI C Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133022/java-jni-c-debugger/13135418#13135418)